# B field outside coil with high mu

Tags: electromagnetism

Would the B field outside a coil made with high $\mu$ (permalloy, mumetal, etc) wire be any stronger than a coil made with regular copper wire? (Assuming all other parameters are the same, current, dimensions etc.)

Comment: Do you mean the coil made out of mumetal or the mumetal inside?

Comment: Coil made of mumetal wire instead of copper, for instance.

Comment: This does not matter,  both the same, if they are the same coils and current